# How to make circle-clip image glyphs in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

How do I add circle-clipped image glyphs to my chart, without processing and uploading the images manually beforehand? I'm open to using other modules.

I want the end result to look something like this chart (from nytimes).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmMYd.jpg

My current understanding is that we can only load images directly from urls, which is not my desired outcome.
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image_url.html

Answer (score 0):

> My current understanding is that we can only load images directly from urls

This is not correct, there is also `ImageRGBA` which allows for sending images as raw RGBA data, directly embedded in the Bokeh document. See, e.g., this gallery example:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image_rgba.html

So assuming that `images` is a Python list of 2D NumPy arrays of RGBA data for the (pre-cropped) images you want to display, then Bokeh could show them with:

```
p.image_rgba(image=images, x=....)
```

Of course, you have to convert the images to RGBA arrays yourself, and also crop them, so things may simply be easier or more ready made for this use-case with another tool.